# how can i set learning rate for big data?

Tags: keras, training, learning-rate, epochs

will it need more epochs for training or it is not a necessary and what is the learning rate I should set for this data with optimizer adam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the default learning rate, then apply the learning rate scheduler to adjust your learning rate in every few epochs. Please refer to the [keras document](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/learning_rate_scheduler/)

Comment: This is alternative approach. You can try one of these. You can use the adam default learning rate in kears as the initial_learning_rate then it will adjust/decay in every few epochs/steps.

Comment: thanks for replying but excuse what about decay_steps and decay_rate? and does the epochs will exceed 20 epochs as a dataset is large

Comment: These are all hyper-parameters. You need to specify in advance. I encourage you to try out few different numbers. (# of steps) * (batch_size) = 1 epoch, it all depends on your data size. Try several sets of decay_steps, decay_rates. Again these are hyper-parameters. BTW, if you think my solution is helpful, please accept my answer and hit up. Thanks